# Getting error while creating a custom element which extends SVGCircleElement

Tags: javascript, svg, web-component, custom-element

I have the following Node class which I am using to create a custom element `node-element`.

```
class Node extends SVGCircleElement{
    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ["coordinates"];
      }
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.attributeMap = {coordinates:(coordinates)=>this.updateCoordinates(coordinates)}
    }
    connectedCallback(){
        this.initNode();
    }
    updateCoordinates(coordinates)
    {
        this.setAttribute("cx",`${coordinates.x}`);
        this.setAttribute("cy",`${coordinates.y}`);
        this.setAttribute("r",50);
    }
    initNode()
    {
        this.className="node";
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(name,oldValue,newValue)
    {
        if(oldValue!==newValue)
        {
            this.attributeMap[name](JSON.parse(newValue))
        }
    }
}
```

I register this element using:-

`customElements.define('node-element',Node);`

I am creating this element as follows:-

`let newNode = document.createElement("node-element");`

This is where I get the following error:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
    at new Node (index.js:9)
    at SVGSVGElement.drawNode (index.js:43)
```

Line 43 corresponds to the createElement code.

Comment: Please try using [document.createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS)

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly to use it with "node-element"?

Comment: Have you succesfuly extended (other) SVG Elements?

Comment: @enxaneta I tried document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","node-element"). This gives no error but none of the constructor or lifecycle methods get called. I verified it using console logs.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman My requirement is to only use the circle element so I have only extended it's class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would love to be proven wrong, just spent 2 months on an SVG project

AFAIK, you can NOT extend SVG elements

You can only create Custom Elements in the HTML Namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`

SVG Elements are in the SVG Namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`

From the docs: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#element-definition

> If the element interface for extends and the HTML namespace is HTMLUnknownElement,
> then throw a "NotSupportedError" DOMException.

and

> if namespace is not the HTML namespace, return null

The ongoing W3C discussion on allowing other namespaces is here: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/634

---

The HTML Namespace has restrictions too

Apple/Safari implemented the *Autonomous Custom Elements* (extend from HTMLElement)
but will not implement *Customized Built-In Elements* (extend any Built-In element from the HTML Namespace)

---

If you want to generate SVG, you have to extend `HTMLElement` and generate the whole SVG tag:

```html
customElements.define("svg-circle", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24'>  
      <circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='48%'/>
    </svg>`;
  }
});
```

#### Related Custom Element SVG StackOverflow Question and Answers

- [Change the background of an active icon on a menu in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63350591/javascript-change-the-background-of-an-active-icon-on-a-menu/63408313#63408313)

Comment: Aww shoots man. Thanks for clarifying this. I have a big svg element, inside which I want to draw various nodes (circles) whenever I click on any point inside the svg. I was able to achieve this feature just using absolute positioning on divs but I got to know that svg is better for stuff like this but no custom element support sucks.

Comment: So, back to oldskool, you can do ``createElement('circle')`` and append it to the SVG. Or create it as String and set the innerHTML on an existing SVG group ``<g>``

Comment: The last link loops back to here.