# How to use SVG icons

Tags: qt, svg, icons

I am learning QT development and planning to use SVG file icons. But I found that many SVG icons are black and white. I think this may be the base color of the icons. It should allow the user to set the color after downloading. But how to set the color?

Additionally, if not using QT, how do people generally use these black and white icons in other situations?

I apologize, upon further reflection I realize I do not have any specific actions to describe or results to share. My previous inquiry was intended merely to gain a broader perspective, rather than to imply I had undertaken any actual efforts. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63350591/change-the-background-of-an-active-icon-on-a-menu-in-javascript/63408313#63408313

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Qt 6, an alternative to what @Atmo suggested is the MultiEffect.

```
import QtQuick.Effects
Image {
    id: iconImage
    source: yourImageURLhere
    visible: false
}
MultiEffect {
    id: overlay
    anchors.centerIn: iconImage
    source: iconImage
    height: iconImage.height
    width: iconImage.width
    colorization: 1.0
    colorizationColor: whateverColorYouWant
}
```

The only limitation is that your SVG file must have all of its strokes (and possibly fills) set to white for this to work - not sure why this is (might be a bug).

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that ColorOverlay doesn't *set* the color specified; it sort of blends the original color with the color specified in the overlay. This may not be what you want (it wasn't what I wanted).

Comment: For the record, I was indeed informed on my answer that the `ColorOverlay` class was deprecated in Qt6. The class does appear in the [All QML Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmltypes.html#c) page but not in the list of [Obsolete QML Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/obsoleteqmltypes.html), and I think it still works (for backward compatibility), so this is something I had missed. They could have done a better job...